# Sublime Text 3 Find - highlight all results, rather than white outline

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

Find in Sublime Text 3 highlights one of the results, and a white outline of the other results.  The white outline (any color outline) is very hard to see.  Is there a way/package to highlight all search results?

Comment: The colors used for those things is controlled by the color scheme that you use.  What version of Sublime and what color scheme are you using?

Comment: Sublime Text 3.1.1., Monokai.  But every color scheme seems the same, with only one Find result highlighted and all the rest with a border box.

Comment: Ahh I see; sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking there. You can alter the colors of things, but Sublime only has one item as "active" or "current" at a time; it's visually distinguishing that for you. In theory a plugin could alter the colors of all of the find results, but I don't think it could do so without trying to somehow provide it's own `find` functionality as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if there's a way to have all the matches highlighted, but you can make them a lot easier to see by changing the colour and making the box thicker.

To do this, create your own colour scheme by adding a new .sublime-color-scheme file to the correct folder. For me (on linux) the simplest way is to copy the default  color scheme file at ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.sublime-color-scheme to ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/my_colors.sublime-color-scheme

Then add the following lines to the 'global' section:

```
"highlight": "var(orange3)",  
"selection_border_width": "2",
```

To use your new colour scheme, select Color Scheme from the Preferences menu - there should now me a new scheme available called 'my_colors'.

Answer (score 1):

Just customize your Color Scheme directly:

Menu, Sublime Text, Settings ..., Customize Color Scheme

On the right side you can add your customization:

```
// Documentation at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html
{
    "variables":
    {
    },
    "globals":
    {
        "highlight": "#ffdf80",  
        "selection_border_width": "2",  
    },
    "rules":
    [
  
    ]
}
```

(I use DA Dark as standard theme, but you can do this with every theme you want)